# registerReceiver BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED not working

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver, bluetoothadapter

I'm working with Android Oreo and bluetooth. I want to get from a broadcast info when a new device is found and when Bluetoothadapter has changed its state. I have the following code:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);

    registerReceiver(BEReceiver_ADD, filter);
    registerReceiver(BEReceiver_Adapter, filter2);
```

why do I recieve signal with BEReceiver_ADD but not with BEReceiver_Adapter? I never enter into BEReceiver_Adapter. What's wrong?

**NOTE:** I tried the same code with Android 4.1 and it works. Why is not working with Android 8.0?

Comment: Do you have ADMIN and ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions? How does the same code work without NPE without changes in getting bluetooth adapter?     if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=18) {
            bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        } else bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Comment: what is NPE? I already had those permissions. About the code you gave me, I just changed but still, ACTION_STATE_CHANGED is not fired. ACTION_FOUND is still fired.

Comment: ACTION_STATE_CHANGED react on adapter's state, like turn on/off. It is difficult to say what problem is without other code. If you don't want to share it, I may recommend to use Bluetooth lib, GitHub.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library - it is work on Android 7-8.1 I've tested by myself.

Comment: oh. Then it is my fault because I was looking for ending the discovery. Thanks, what I was looking for it was ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED. Then maybe I should recheck the code I had with Android 4.1. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I need to publish it as an answer?

Comment: I'll accept it if you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED produced by bluetooth adapter state changing, like turn on/off. Also in newer android versions method of getting adapter object changed, so the code to have backward compatibility should look like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) { 
     BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE); 
     bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter(); 
} else bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Also I may recommend to use [library](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library) to work with Rfcomm profile - because it significantly reduce amount of support code and gives comfortable in callbacks.